# Handle save as dialog box by selenium web driver in java

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automation, webdriver

I'm Trying to save a Html Page using Selenium script in java which perform following operations

1. open the web page.
2. fire a right click event.
3. click on save as html option.

Now problem is when script click on save as html option it shows a pop-up to save html.

I already set default option for download in Firefox but when i run the script it keep showing me pop-up again and again what i need is:-

1. when Firefox shows a save as dialog box then it'll fire an enter event so that it can save html by using Selenium script.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Robot` class in java might help you. Check this [link](http://www.softwaretestinghelp.com/handle-alerts-popups-selenium-webdriver-selenium-tutorial-16/) as well.

Here is a sample code:

```
// Create object of Robot class<br>
Robot object=new Robot();

// Press Enter<br>
object.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);

// Release Enter<br>
object.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
```

Comment: Is the robot class required to handle Dialog boxes?

Comment: @Ken J yes you need to use Robot class to handle dialog box... because you need to fire an enter event when dialog button appear in firefox.... and you can do this while running your script in selenium...

Answer (score 1):

Window pop ups cant be handled by Selenium.So you can go for follwing options : -

(1) Java Robot Class

(2) [Sikuli](http://www.sikuli.org) [Recommended]

(3) AutoIt

These are 3rd party tools used to handle window based pop ups.

Comment: Hi Thanks for your replay. Actually we already try some AutoIt code but not able to find any useful solution for this problem

Answer (score 1):

Accepting confirmation popups in Selenium can be handled via `Alert` object (assuming driver instance is ready):

```
Alert myAlert = driver.switchTo().alert();
myAlert.accept();
```

Comment: Sorry, seems it's not what you want :) I was about confirmation popups

Comment: Hi Thanks. But sir its not a alert it is a Save As Dialog Box.

Comment: As a workaround for firefox, you can set up browser preferences with default download folder :) then it will not show this dialog

Answer (score 1):

Use autoit
download the autoit exe
record clicking of that button 
Use the code and execute it via JS executor

Dont forget to place the code before you are actually executing the step
not after executing it

Answer (score 0):

Please switch to windows dialogs first using get window handles eg. Save As

Then, use Robot commands to send Enter key.
It will save the file.